# How do I restore backup from timeshift from external usb device

Tags: 16.04, backup

I know that it is really easy to restore from previous timeshift backup on the same machine, but I have my backup files on an external hard-drive and I wonder how to restore my system directly from the backup files on that external hard drive?

It was advertised that Timeshift can help restore backups even when the system is broken (using a live CD), but Timeshift itself didn't give an example or tutorial regarding how that could be done. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "Broken."  If you have messed up your OS, and the system will not boot, Timeshift should work, if you have a damaged Hard Drive, probably not, because the files are on the existing hard drive.
Procedure to restore a messed up system: 
Boot from the live CD
Open the Menu from the main screen, Timeshift should be under Administration.  It is accessible from the live boot.
Select Timeshift and restore your selected backup.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @erry, I'm wondering if there exists a solution similar to "Time Machine" on Mac, which allows you to back up your entire OS (and data) to an external hard-drive and recover in full whenever your system is messed up or some crucial data is lost